# Dealing with spam with an unknown party harvesting the email address

Tags: email, privacy, spam

I have a situation where I keep receiving spam from several IT companies (solicitations, marketing etc.). I think I gave away my email to a company in the last couple of years for reading a white paper or something (I do not remember at all). And that company has been selling my email to various IT firms.

I reached out to a couple of companies asking them about how they were able to gather my email address but they were not willing to disclose.

What's the best (if any) way to deal with a SPAM situation like this?

Comment: Ideally you gave each company a separate address. For example by using the recipient delimiter (my default `+`), e.g. `user+companyxyz.tld@example.com`. Not all mail provider support this.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States the CAN-SPAM Act of 2003 regulates all commercial e-mail.  You can try e-mailing each company individually and telling them they don't have your permission to contact you and if they don't you will file a complaint with the FTC.  You can find out more information here:

http://www.fcc.gov/guides/spam-unwanted-text-messages-and-email

You can file a complaint here:

https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov

You could also look at complaining to their ISP.

in reality, though, once your e-mail is out it's OUT.  You will get more and more messages.  The easiest fix would be to switch e-mail addresses.  If this is not possible there are a range of spam filtering services from local programs you use on your computer to hosted solutions.  The latter are usually more expensive but also more effective.  One exception is that some commercial e-mail hosts such as google can take over hosting your e-mail for a very small fee (around $5 per address per month) and are VERY good at filtering spam.

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice, when some spam marketing companies outbid email addresses from each other. http://securelist.com/threats/the-spam-market-infrastructure/
If once your address has got to spam database of emails addresses there isn't chance to remove this one from there. Possibly, IT companies, which mailing to you white papers, didn't sell your address, and your address has been stolen from them or from service of email mailings, which they used to mailing you white papers. In this case you can try to use some anti spam filter, it can reduce amount spam in your inbox, but unlikely get rid of all spam emails. And of course, spammers could find your address by other way, and not by IT companies, which know your email address.